# Multi apk from Unity3d for differents architectures

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, x86, apk

I want to publish 2 apk on google store (made with unity), using the multi-apk feature.
I looked on internet and i tried this :

- Created a Application.mk at ProjectFolder/jni/
  with only `APP_ABI := x86`  or `APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a` depending on the lib I wanted to use.
- Created 2 apk with 2 version code with Unity 'device filtrer' settings to x86 or Ar Mv 7, depending on the apk I wanted to build.
- Published both apk on google develloper console.

The Apk have not the same size, so different libs are used. (With both lib, the apk weight 16 mo more, with only arm, like ~8mo more and with only x86 like ~8.5mo).

The problem is, 'native platform' detected by google console is always 'armeabi-v7a, x86' (both architectures), no matter the apk.
So I get a error message on google console saying that both apk have exaclty same device compatibility.

(PS: if I want 2 differents apk, it's because each lib take 8mo on the final apk, so 16mo for an empty project. And with google size limitation for apk...)

---

### Update :

Ok the probleme was from a plugin (everyplay).It had libs for x86 and arm architechture. The solution was to remove the x86 plugin lib before building the arm apk, and to remove arm plugin lib to build the x86 apk.
I also noticed that changing `APP_ABI` in Application.mk was not necessary, the unity parameter `device filtrer` override it.

Comment: Some x86 Android devices support armeabi/armeabi-v7a native libraries by means of binary code translation (e.g. libhoudini).

Comment: Does it mean that i should only include armeabi/armeabi-v7a libraries? What problems can encounter x86 Android devices?
By the way, what's the current proportion of x86 devices?

Comment: x86 devices IIRC were less than 500 around 2 months ago.

Comment: It's a lot! What will happen if x86 device user download an apk without x86 lib (as google console think it's compatible even without the appropriate lib) ? Simply crash on load or just bad performances (with code translation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Google is pointing this out, it means that somewhere Unity is overriding / including files for x86 even when you're trying to build for ARM. Here's a couple of things you should do

1. Open Unity's `Player Settings`, go to the `Android` tab, select `Other Settings`and under *Configuration -> Device Filter* select whatever architecture you want to build for (Default is both)
2. This one is a little more un-intuitive. Just because you do step 1 above, doesn't ALWAYS mean that only 1 architecture gets built. If a plugin, it it's `/lib` folder includes ANY files that are for both architectures, then both architectures are built. So you need to manually comb through each plugi folder and ensure that there's no such files.

Comment: The thing is, when I choose to build for only one architecture (instead of both), the apk size if effectivly reduced by half (we can conclude that only one lib is built, even if google console think it's compatible for both).
But I will try to remove all plugins (remove plugin directory) anyway, i'll tell you if it work.

Comment: Ok it works ! That was a puglin (everyplay) that imported libs for x86 and arm. I removed the x86 and the apk is was only compatible (for google console) with arm devices. Thanks!